# Dict comprehension not working like I thought it does. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Dict comprehension with if-else condition does not seem to be using the if block at all. It always goes to the else block even when it should not.

I am trying to use dict comprehension with if condition in python to determine the number of occurrences of characters in a string. However, the if condition never seems to be satisfied (when it really should be). Only the else condition seems to be satisfied

```py
def letter_count(input_str):
    letter_count_map = {}

    letter_count_map = {letter: letter_count_map[letter]+1 if letter in 
                        letter_count_map.keys() else 1 
                        for letter in input_str}
    print(letter_count_map)


letter_count("serendipity")
```

Expected result:

```
{'s': 1, 'e': 2, 'r': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1, 'i': 2, 'p': 1, 't': 1, 'y': 1}
```

Actual result:

```
{'s': 1, 'e': 1, 'r': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1, 'i': 1, 'p': 1, 't': 1, 'y': 1}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @pylang Thanks for the pointer. Will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`letter_count_map` isn't assigned its new value until after the `dict` comprehension is fully evaluated.  Before that happens, it's just the empty `dict`, and so nothing will be in its `keys()`.  What you're trying to do should instead be done with a loop instead of a comprehension:

```
letter_count_map = {}
for letter in input_str:
    letter_count_map[letter] = letter_count_map[letter]+1 if letter in letter_count_map.keys() else 1
```

Comment: Side-note: `letter_count_map[letter]+1 if letter in letter_count_map.keys() else 1` is a *really* slow/verbose way to spell `letter_count_map.get(letter, 0) + 1`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for the response. To clarify though, are you saying `letter_count_map.get(letter, 0) + 1` is more performant? If so, why is it more performant?

Comment: @GopinathTaget: It avoids creating an unnecessary keys view (though you could drop the `.keys()` from the original code to get the same effect), avoids a containment test followed by a lookup in favor of just the lookup, and avoids branching byte code instructions. It might not be that much faster (method calls have some annoyingly high fixed overhead, though it's been reduced in 3.7 if you're calling with purely positional args), but it's a *lot* shorter/clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You also can take `defaultdict` to simplify your code.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def letter_count(input_str):
    letter_count_map = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    for c in input_str:
        letter_count_map[c] += 1
    print(letter_count_map)

letter_count("serendipity")
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I will check it out.

Comment: FYI, `defaultdict(int)` will accomplish the same goal. No need for a `lambda`.

Comment: Or even shorter:
`collections.Counter("serendipity")`
It all depends if you're writing the code to learn, or if you have a real problem to solve.